# Unnecessary space between list items

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Maybe this is by design, but

- I don't think
- there needs to be
- so much space
- between list items.

Jin, would you consider removing the margin-bottom?

```
.post-text ul li, .post-text ol li { margin-bottom: 1em }
```

Comment: Having said that, I hope there will be at least a bit of space between list items because in the previous design, list items had a line-height that was so tight everything looked like one big block of text. It was hard to format things in easy to read lists.

Comment: @Rahul The change is in. He cut the margin in half rather than removing it entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I think  it looks great having extra space. It allows the list to breathe a bit and really helps break up the different points. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Yes, there's now half has much space as when I asked and I think it's good now. Should have done a screenshot.

Comment: Haha, well great, it looks perfect!